# Reset iOS app in background after some time

Tags: ios

I am trying to reset my iOS app's state when it is becoming active after being in the background for (say) 30 seconds.

I know about setting `Application does not run in background mode` and `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in plist but this will reset the state of the app immediately rather than after some time. Is there a way to trigger this after the app has been in the background for some time?

Answer (score 2):

in AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground: will call when app enter background. You save enterBackGroundTime here

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

and when it enter foreground `applicationWillEnterForeground:` (if app in background to foreground) or `- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (if app killed and launch again) will call. You get enterForeGroundTime here

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

You count difference between enterBackGroundTime and enterForeGroundTime to get it

Comment: How to "difference"? I don't think this is an optimal method anyway... There should be a timer some place...

Comment: enterBackGroundTime = [NSDate date]; and enterForeGroundTime = [NSDate date];. You can use NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate: to get diffrence in seconds.

Comment: when you first run the app, won't applicationWillEnterForeground be called? If so, then foregroundTime - backGroundTime (which is nil or 0) will always be greater than 30 seconds... I gave you a +1 but I'll wait to see if I can get a better answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes I did change answer